# toString method for binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Please help me to fix my code.

For the `toString` method, the string should be formatted as

```
{currentData, leftSubtree, rightSubtree}
```

An empty tree should return an empty set of brackets `{}`.

for the Junit test I'm getting:

```
Expected: {5, {0, {-5, {}, {}}, {3, {}, {}}}, {10, {7, {}, {}}, {13, {}, {}}}}
Actual:   {5, {0, {-5, {}, {3, {}, {}, {10, {7, {}, {13, {}, {}, {}}
```

This is my code:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer("{");
    toString(root, string);
    string.append("}");
    return string.toString();
}

private void toString(BSTNode<T> node, StringBuffer string) {

    if (node != null) {
        string.append(node.getData());
        if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            string.append(", " + "{");
            toString(node.getLeft(), string);
        }
        if (node.getRight() != null) {
            string.append(", " + "{");
            toString(node.getRight(), string);
        }
    }
    string.append(", {}");
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you traced through the code in your IDE debugger? What do you see?

Comment: You never write out an end brace after you recurse

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Every node will unconditionally append `", {}"`, whether empty or not? *Really?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code adds `{` before calling itself recursively, but doesn't add `}` upon return. This applies to both recursion calls.

Also, your code unconditionally appends `, {}`, even for non-empty trees.

---

Instead, write your recursive method to do exactly what you said:

- Format as `{currentData, leftSubtree, rightSubtree}`
- Format empty tree as `{}`

Don't make it the callers job to add the `{` `}` around the value, because that will duplicate the logic (DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself).

Expected output also shows that a leaf node should format as `{value, {}, {}}`, not as `{value}`, which is what your code does with those extra `if` statements.

Also, don't use `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder`, and the recursive method can be `static`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    toString(this.root, string);
    return string.toString();
}
private static <T> void toString(BSTNode<T> node, StringBuilder string) {
    string.append('{');
    if (node != null) {
        string.append(node.getData());
        string.append(", ");
        toString(node.getLeft(), string);
        string.append(", ");
        toString(node.getRight(), string);
    }
    string.append('}');
}
```

If you make the recursive method return the `StringBuilder`, your code can become smaller, if you like condensing your code. Makes no difference, functionally or performance-wise. It reads better if you flip the parameters.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return toString(new StringBuilder(), this.root).toString();
}
private static <T> StringBuilder toString(StringBuilder string, BSTNode<T> node) {
    string.append('{');
    if (node != null) {
        string.append(node.getData());
        toString(string.append(", "), node.getLeft());
        toString(string.append(", "), node.getRight());
    }
    return string.append('}');
}
```

Comment: you won :) +1 for the last piece